# Can TypeScript interfaces be identified as the interface they inherit from?

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance, interface

I have a TypeScript interface that is meant to be extended by many other interfaces. For example, call it `Parent` and say 2 interfaces extend `Parent` and are called `ChildA` and `ChildB`. In reality there are many more children inheriting from `Parent`.

```js
interface Parent {
  sharedProp: string;
}

interface ChildA extends Parent {
  uniqueChildAProp: string;
}

interface ChildB extends Parent {
  uniqueChildBProp: string;
}
```

Is there a way I can have another interface `Grandparent` that is defined similar to as follows:

```js
interface Grandparent {
  children: Parent[];
}
```

Where the elements in the `children` array can be `ChildA` or `ChildB` (or any other interface that extends `Parent`)?

This would be a valid `Grandparent`:

```js
const concrete: Grandparent = {
  children: [
    {
      sharedProp: 'fooA',
      uniqueChildAProp: 'barA'
    },
    {
      sharedProp: 'foo',
      uniqueChildBProp: 'barB'
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to avoid unioning the types `ChildA, ChildB, etc.` since there are likely to be a lot of inheritors of `Parent`.

Comment: But that's exactly what a type-union is for: it's the only way to define a closed-set of types. But you **can** use `type Grandchild = ChildA | ChildB | etc`` and then use the name `Grandchild` instead of repeating that type-union expression everywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to restrict `Grandparent`'s `children` property to be an array of just *known* extensions of `Parent`, then a union is the only way.  If, on the other hand, you wish to accept `Parent` and *all structurally compatible* extensions, even ones that haven't been declared yet... then you don't need to change the definition at all.

Your existing `Grandparent` definition *already* allows the elements of the `children` property to be a `Parent` or any subtype of `Parent` like `ChildA` or `ChildB`.  The issue you might be running into is that, when you use an object literal like you did with `concrete`, the compiler performs [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) and complains about properties it doesn't expect:

```
const concrete: Grandparent = {
  children: [
    {
      sharedProp: 'fooA',
      uniqueChildAProp: 'barA' // error!
    },
    {
      sharedProp: 'foo',
      uniqueChildBProp: 'barB' // error!
    }
  ]
};
```

But that doesn't mean that you can't pass a `ChildA` or `ChildB`; it just means that you need to *tell* the compiler that you *intend* to have a `ChildA` or `ChildB` so that the properties are not unexpected:

```
const cA: ChildA = { sharedProp: 'fooA', uniqueChildAProp: 'barA' };
const cB: ChildB = { sharedProp: 'foo', uniqueChildBProp: 'barB' };
const concrete1: Grandparent = { children: [cA, cB] };
```

Or you can refactor in a number of other ways to appease the compiler and avoid excess property checking:

```
const children = [
  {
    sharedProp: 'fooA',
    uniqueChildAProp: 'barA'
  },
  {
    sharedProp: 'foo',
    uniqueChildBProp: 'barB'
  }
];
const concrete2: Grandparent = { children }; // okay
```

---

If you want to allow subtypes of `Parent` without complaining about extra properties in object literals, you might decide to use an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) because object literals are implicitly compatible with appropriate index signatures.  Like this:

```
interface AnyParent extends Parent {
  [k: string]: unknown;
}

interface Grandparent2 {
  children: AnyParent[];
}

const concrete3: Grandparent2 = {
  children: [
    {
      sharedProp: 'fooA',
      uniqueChildAProp: 'barA'
    },
    {
      sharedProp: 'foo',
      uniqueChildBProp: 'barB'
    }
  ]
}; // okay
```

That works for your example code.  Be careful though; according to [microsoft/TypeScript#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300), `interface` types are *not* implicitly compatible with index signatures, so using an explicit `ChildA` annotation will no longer work:

```
const childA: ChildA = { sharedProp: "", uniqueChildAProp: "" };
const oops: Grandparent2 = { children: [childA] }; // error!
```

So an index signature is really only advisable if you only care about object literals and type aliases and not interfaces.  Therefore I'd probably suggest the first option and refactor, annotate, or [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) that you are intentionally adding extra properties.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApyhcyDeBYAKGWQGcALDCAE1SgHsAHALlLClAHMBuQgX0MKhIsRCgDCZYABsqAQWQQAHpBBUSaStnxFkAVxDAAjrogTpc2oxYk2nHgX4FB4aPCTIzMgEILlWNRqYWoTE+kYmnlRelsys7CDcfCHOwm4oAOJQcKoMmmC4IcgIkjJBLOhBYADaALr2joQIdCA2Rc0ImJAsmdlUuZXIALwFOsXmZchVhcTaxHOkFJg09LEA5DB0dLKrADTTc2HGpiUWKyyrAEYY28gA9LcKUPRQAIT7vHs6M-vE5JTLVmQ602ux+egMR0i0TOQKuUC8qzuD2gzzeX2QjmINT49kazVaCFkLEi8mGOAW-xi5w2W124PCx3MsipsOuiN49iaLXyCC8xJOPjJFKWLOBdDphwiAtFcIRGM5+J57U6EAAjN0sjk8kNcEUThMqoSdkUvDV5QICFyCfqsDqpjpZnM-iKYWLtp95pLGTJma64dtCh9Co7fotqKKaaD0V6oTKMAjA4Q6njuW0QB0IJAAEwa3r9LD5IVjUq2jkWoSuUTIWQgACeFQLvhUAQbwR0VQA1tZbAkaix9B2QHQAO4gerllwidw9LWVLMjYjFqgTGv1vK1cdOS2KtMZyAAZlzs4L87JhSXBv2IadYYBaxp7rBMZOvsBlzZ7w9c2vocprsjX6ehCUrmNCb6yqs7yFNiDhcEiyB0B2cC1haVo8i+-JMjq5LOuGMIAET4caz5MiyhHmtuqabAwJBHn0eSnrqF5YCwhovmaHLwSidCvIQQA)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Very helpful for understanding the issue I was running into.